# Merge webcam video and canvas drawing together in JS

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, video, merge

I'm trying to merge webcam video and canvas drawing and save to an image file. It works but video image covers canvas draving. I tried to swap places context.drawImage but still same. Any ideas? :)

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", async function () {
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width / 1.5, canvas.height / 1.5);
    context.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "./upload.php",
      data: {
        dataURL: dataURL
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently what you code does is to draw the canvas over itself, with the video already painted on it.
You can draw behind the existing content by using the [`globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation).

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "16px sans-serif";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
const img = new Image(); // a video is the same
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png";
img.decode().then(() => {
  canvas.onclick = (evt) => {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // reset to default
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  };
  
  ctx.fillText("click on the canvas", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 3);
  ctx.fillText("to draw the image", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 3 + 20);
  ctx.fillText("behind this text", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 3 + 40);
});
```

```css
canvas { outline: 1px solid }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```